# List from Int to specific Strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, dictionary

What would I do if I wanted to turn a list of `Int`s such as `[1,2,3]` to `["∧","∨","→"]` (so if there is a '1' turn it into the '∧' etc...)

Answer (score 8):

I would probably do it in two steps:

```
conv :: Int -> String
conv 1 = "∧"
conv 2 = "∨"
conv 3 = "→"
```

And then just map that:

```
change :: [Int] -> [String]
change = map conv

change [1,2,3] -- returns ["∧","∨","→"]
```

You could even embed:

```
change = map conv
  where
    conv 1 = "∧"
    ...
```